# Reallocating **array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

My 2d array char **buffer is being created. The malloc part works. The realloc part is generating a segmentation error.

These are the 2 functions which do the following;

```
//sets up the array initially
void setBuffer(){
buffer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*buf_x);

for(int x=0;x<buf_x;x++){
    buffer[x] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*buf_y);
}

if(buffer==NULL){
    perror("\nError: Failed to allocate memory");
}
}

//changes size
//variable buf_x has been modified
void adjustBuffer(){
for(int x=prev_x; x<buf_x;x++) {
    buffer[x] = NULL;
}

buffer=(char**)realloc(buffer,sizeof(char*)*buf_x);

for(int x=0; x<buf_x;x++){
    buffer[x]  = (char*)realloc(buffer[x],sizeof(char)*buf_y);
    strcpy(buffer[x],output_buffer[x]);
}
if(buffer == NULL){
    perror("\nError: Failed to adjust memory");
}
}
```

Comment: but how can I change the size of the buffer, and at the same time not removing the elements within it? or should i save the elements in the array and then put them back in the reallocated one? thank you

Comment: @xing i have modified the code. can you check whether ive followed your advice please. thank you

Comment: That`s a jagged array, not a 2D array! Completely different datatype!

Comment: @xing so the should i just set buffer[0] = NULL at the beginning of the function adjustBuffer? thanks

Comment: [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: A *pointer to pointer to char* is not an *array of arrays of type char*. Always `realloc` with a `tmp` pointer and not the actual variable. If `realloc` fails, you lose your reference to the original block of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `buf_x` is global.
You will need to store the original size and pass it to the function.
If elements are added, the new elements need to be set to NULL so `realloc` will succeed.

```
//variable buf_x has been modified
void adjustBuffer( int original){
    buffer=realloc(buffer,sizeof(char*)*buf_x);
    for(int x=original; x<buf_x;x++){
        buffer[x] = NULL;//set new pointers to NULL
    }
    for(int x=0; x<buf_x;x++){
        buffer[x]  = realloc(buffer[x],sizeof(char)*buf_y);
    }
}
```

check if realloc fails

```
//variable buf_x has been modified
void adjustBuffer( int original){
    if ( ( buffer = realloc ( buffer, sizeof(char*) * buf_x)) != NULL) {
        for ( int x = original; x < buf_x; x++) {
            buffer[x] = NULL;//set new pointers to NULL
        }
        for ( int x = 0; x < buf_x; x++){
            if ( ( buffer[x] = realloc ( buffer[x], strlen ( output_buffer[x]) + 1)) == NULL) {
                break;
            }
            strcpy(buffer[x],output_buffer[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. but it is still giving me a segmentation fault